Inherit project dependencies in Rust
I have 2 libraries written in rust: ALib and BLib. BLib depends on ALib. The uuid dependency is enabled in ALib. Does BLib not inherit the default uuid dependency in rust? And is it possible to make it dependent automatically so as not to register this dependency manually in cargo BLib?

Umm, isn't it already pulled in if you use cargo? Like Alib::uuid? I am not sure, but you should try that.

It helped after I added in ALib lib.rs pub extern crate uuid; and in BLib use ALib::uuid;

Dependencies are private by default. You should export them manually if they're part of your API.
// either export the whole thing
pub use uuid;
// or export just the part relevant to your library
pub use uuid::Uuid;

Keep in mind that as long as the version specifiers are compatible, Cargo will only compile a dependency once no matter how many times it shows up in the dependency graph.

...but it is still a good practice to export them (I know, you've said that).
